# Showing that a direct product is non-cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra

We have that $Z_{2} \times Z_{2}$ is non cyclic this can be easy seen by that $(2,2) \neq 1$ or simply by writing out the table, but I am searching for another method which I was introduced in during class. If I remember correctly it had something to do with LCM and perhaps Lagrange? Does anyone know about this method?

So my question is basically how do I know that the direct product is non-cyclic without using coprime method and by inspection, but using LCM

Comment: A cyclic group of order $n$ must contain an element of order $n$. Note that $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ has order $4$; does it have an element of order $4$? You can play around with this idea to get a general condition on when a direct product of finitely many finite cyclic groups is cyclic.

Comment: Yes I am well aware of this, and this is one of the reasons why $Z_{2} \times Z_{2}$ is not isomorphic to $Z_{4}$ but not sure on how I can turn this argument into a method of showing how a larger finite group is cyclic, by using LCM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If $\gcd(m,n)>1$ then $C_m \times C_n$ is not cyclic.

Indeed, let $L=\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$. Then $g^L = 1$ for all $g \in C_m \times C_n$. Since
$$
L = \frac{mn}{\gcd(m,n)} < mn
$$
there is no element of order $mn$ in $C_m \times C_n$.